# How to give remove field name from custom error message + rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

> How to remove field name from model in error message
>   `module RankStudentModel

```
    def self.included (base)
        base.instance_eval do
            validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, :scope => [:batch_id, :phone2, :middle_name, :last_name], :message => "Student with same Name and Mobile number is already Present in the Batch " 
        end
    end
```

> In this above model validation i need to skip first_name error message and only i need to display custom message given.

Comment: You mean the text that is displayed in your view when you render errors?

Comment: Yes Exactly i am working in rails 2 @nvugteveen